# Favicon won't appear on any mobile or desktop browser

Tags: html, browser, web, favicon

My question may sound stupid, I've made a lot of websites already, but I'm not able to figure this out.

I've set a favicon for the website and it's not appearing in any browser.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

If I open the direct URL I can see the icon, the tag is in the `<head>` correctly.

I have already looked for other Q&A here and on Google, still not working :(

Comment: It works in my browser :) Cache maybe?

Comment: Which browser are you using?
I've tried Chrome and Firefox and none of those worked :(

I've already deleted my cache on both of those

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7pf41j Firefox

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know why I still can't see that (even on firefox.. you're using that right?)

Cleared the cache twice and restarted the browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearead the cache multiple times, reopened the browser: no luck

Rebooted PC and voilà, suddendly working xD

SOLVED, thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

I can see your favicon here, an yellow coloured icon with black tick isnt is ?

Sometimes takes a while for the browser to pick it up. Try a different browser / PC to see or post the url.

if still you are not getting , do as follows::

**1-**  Close Chrome

**2-** Open your User Data folder (http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)

**3-** Delete the Favicons file

**4-** Run Chrome

**5-** Visit sites to force the icons to be re-downloaded

Comment: Nevermind, clearead the cache three time, reopened the browser twice... No luck

Rebooted PC and voilà, suddendly working xD

Comment: yes I don't know why it wasn't working the first time though (lol)

Comment: it is because, browser has little laziness to load the favicon all the time.